# Creating directories in VS C++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am working on an existing C++ (unmanaged) project, that is neatly structured in directories etc. Ridiculous question: how can I create a new directory directly from VS 2010? The only relevant option I can see is to add a new filter, but this doesn't add a new directory (I did check).

Answer (score 1):

On the top of the solution explorer you should have the option "Show all Files". This is a small icon on the top of the solution explorer pane. If you do this, the right click "Add New Item" menu option will now contain "New Folder" rather than "New Filter".

If you prefer the filters view (it is sometimes handy for grouping files across directories into, well, filters) then you can always create directories as part of the browse button for the location when adding a new item.